# How do I turn an api link into something useful?

Tags: json, api, dictionary

I haven't tried much like this before, so I want to know what is the recommended route for doing what I want to do.

I'm trying out the PunchFork.com api which returns recipes in a JSON dictionary. [Here's an example](http://api.punchfork.com/recipes?key=7d6e9bb6ceb947c6&q=turkey&count=4).

How would I go about returning the "title", "thumb", and "pf_url" for each recipe so that I can display them on the page? Currently there is a couple of selects which values are used to create the url, but I don't know what to do with that url in order to display data on the page.

If you have any questions just ask.

Answer (score 0):

What language are you using to generate the webpage? Most languages have built-in mechanisms for turning a JSON string into an object that the language understands.

Here's an example that uses PHP to generate an HTML page with all of the images from the API you referenced:

```
$response = file_get_contents($url);

$object = json_decode($response);

// Now $object is an object with the same data represented in the JSON string,
//   and you can refer to its class members accordingly:

foreach ($object->recipes as $recipe)
{
    $imageUrl = $recipe->source_img;
    echo '<img src="$imageUrl" />';
}
```

Comment: I'm only using HTML, CSS and jQuery so far. Haven't used PHP.